# Opengl-FrameBuffer Object Not Working on real device

Tags: android, opengl-es

I want to capture the rendered scene in my Android openGl App in A Texture Using FrameBuffer Object.

EveryThing is Fine in the emulator, But on Real Device the frameBuffer Object wouldn't work,

meaning Nothing Goes to my Texture, Here is the FBO Class (For Creating FrameBuffer and creating texture of it):

```
public class FBO {
    int [] fb, renderTex;
    int [] TextureBank;
    int top;
    int texW; 
    int texH;    
    int maxTextures;
    public FBO(int width,int height,int maxTextures){
        texW = width; 
        texH = height;
        fb = new int[1];
        renderTex= new int[1];
        top=-1;
        this.maxTextures = maxTextures;
        TextureBank = new int[maxTextures];
    }
    public void setup(GL10 gl){
        // generate
        ((GL11ExtensionPack)gl).glGenFramebuffersOES(1, fb, 0); 
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        gl.glGenTextures(1, renderTex, 0);// generate texture
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderTex[0]);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,
                GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE); 
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,
                GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);  
        //texBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(buf.length*4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asIntBuffer();
        //gl.glTexEnvf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE,GL10.GL_MODULATE);
        gl.glTexImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL10.GL_RGBA, texW, texH, 0, GL10.GL_RGBA, GL10.GL_FLOAT, null);
        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D); 
        if(top>=maxTextures-1){ 
            Log.e("OUT OF TEXTURE COUNTS", "OUT OF TEXTURE COUNTS Texture WIll Not Be added to Stack");
        }
        else{
        TextureBank [++top]= renderTex[0];
        Log.d("TOP= ", "" + top);
        }
    }  


    public boolean RenderStart(GL10 gl){
        // Bind the framebuffer
        ((GL11ExtensionPack)gl).glBindFramebufferOES(GL11ExtensionPack.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, fb[0]);

        // specify texture as color attachment
        ((GL11ExtensionPack)gl).glFramebufferTexture2DOES(GL11ExtensionPack.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL11ExtensionPack.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderTex[0], 0);

        int error = gl.glGetError();
        if (error != GL10.GL_NO_ERROR) {
            Log.d("err", "FIRST Background Load GLError: " + error+"      ");
        }
        int status = ((GL11ExtensionPack)gl).glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL11ExtensionPack.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES);
        if (status != GL11ExtensionPack.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES)
        {
            Log.d("err", "SECOND Background Load GLError: " + status+"      ");;
            return true;
        }
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        return true;
    } 

    public void RenderEnd(GL10 gl){
        ((GL11ExtensionPack)gl).glBindFramebufferOES(GL11ExtensionPack.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, 0);

        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
        gl.glColor4f(1,1,1,1);
        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }

    public int getTexture(){
        return renderTex[0];
    }


}
```

And here is my OnDrawFrame Method Which uses this FBO:

```
public synchronized void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    mObserver.onDrawFrame();
    gl.glClearColor(Color.red(mBackgroundColor) / 255f,
            Color.green(mBackgroundColor) / 255f,
            Color.blue(mBackgroundColor) / 255f,
            Color.alpha(mBackgroundColor) / 255f);
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    gl.glLoadIdentity();




    if(capture){

    if(AttachTexture){
    int h = gl.glGetError();
    /**
    Setup FBO
    */
    frameBuffer.setup(gl);
    if(h!=0){
        Log.d("ERROR", "ERROR Happend"+h+"");
    }
    AttachTexture = false;
    }

    /**
    Start Rendering In FBO
    */
    frameBuffer.RenderStart(gl);  


    if (USE_PERSPECTIVE_PROJECTION) { 
        double x = mCurlMesh.GetMinX()* mCurlMesh.GetMinY();
        gl.glTranslatef((float)(-1.000-mCurlMesh.GetMinX()),(float)(-1.000-mCurlMesh.GetMinY()), -6f);
    } 

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity(); 


    GLU.gluOrtho2D(gl, (float)mCurlMesh.GetMinX(), (float)mCurlMesh.GetMaxX(),
            (float)mCurlMesh.GetMinY(), (float)mCurlMesh.GetMaxY());
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();    
    gl.glViewport(0, 0,texW,texH);
    mCurlMesh.onDrawFrame(gl);    

    /**
    End Rendering In FBO
    */
    frameBuffer.RenderEnd(gl); 

    }  

    //Reset Every Thing to Its Normal State
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    GLU.gluOrtho2D(gl, -1.1f,1.1f,-1.1f, 1.1f);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, mViewportWidth, mViewportHeight);



    mCurlMesh.onDrawFrame(gl);
}
```

I Should mention that my Texture size IS 2^n:

```
frameBuffer  = new FBO(1024, 1024, 8);
```